# bootstrap collapse div show 1 hide 1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i no sure why it is no working. maybe i miss some simple thing== i no sure why what i want is when i use a icon show 1 div than other div will hide.

now is if i click 1st icon show a div if i click the second icon the div will show but the 1st icon div will not hide

here is the example of [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/nonstop328/vVsAn/5082/)

here is the html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="right-lower-container accordion" id="myGroup">
  <div class="testing-notification">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment notification-bar accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#testing1" data-parent="#myGroup"></span>
    <div id="testing1" class="collapse notification-block">
      testing 1
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="testing-notification">
  <span class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-bell notification-bar accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#testing2" data-parent="#myGroup"></span>
  <div id="testing2" class="collapse notification-block">
    testing2
  </div>
  </div>
  <a class="option-font" href="#">
    <span>
      new items
    </span>
  </a>
  <a class="option-font" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
       search
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

here is my css code

```
.right-lower-container {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
}

.notification-bar {
  color: black;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.notification-bar:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.notification-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.testing-notification {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

#testing1,#testing2{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
}

.option-font,
.notification-bar,
.testing-notification {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Additional Question

[image]

how i style the input type by using bootstrap?

here is the html code

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type = "submit" clas="btn btn-default btn-direct-message" value="message" name="chat">
</form>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, or maybe you need to be more clear. what are you trying to achieve? what is the expected result?

Comment: what i want is when i use the span icon open a div right? if i click another icon the 1st div will hide than the 2nd div will out

Answer (score 0):

To style Bootstrap components you need to wrap the input into "form-group" class

```
<form method="post" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type = "submit" clas="btn btn-default btn-direct-message"     value="message" name="chat">
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Want To Collapse A div When The Other Gets Open Try The Following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="container">
   <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
   <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
   </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
   <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
   </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
   <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
   </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
   <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
  
 </body>
    </html>
```